# Is there a way to prevent a stackoverflow on this FluentValidation?

Tags: fluentvalidation

I have the following validation, and I cannot make any way not to get a stackOverflow. Is there any way?

```
public GridLayoutModelValidator()
    {
       //some validations
       RuleFor(layout => layout.Rows).NotEmpty().SetCollectionValidator(new GridLayoutRowModelValidator());
    }
}

public class GridLayoutRowModelValidator : AbstractValidator<GridLayoutRowModel>
{
    public GridLayoutRowModelValidator()
    {
        //some validations
        RuleFor(row => row.Modules).Cascade(CascadeMode.Continue).NotEmpty()
            .SetCollectionValidator(new GridLayoutModuleDataModelValidator());
    }
}

public class GridLayoutModuleDataModelValidator : AbstractValidator<GridLayoutModuleDataModel>
{
    public GridLayoutModuleDataModelValidator()
    {
        //some validations
        RuleFor(module => module.Rows).SetCollectionValidator(new GridLayoutRowModelValidator());      
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show model classes and context of validation call (controller action for example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was awnser here:
https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/discussions/573802